# Two query parameters in a url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Previously, I have defined a state of ui-router which has `connected` as parameter:

```
    .state('addinEdit', {
        url: '/addin/edit/{id}?connected',
        resolve: {
            test: [$stateParams, function($stateParams) {
                console.log($statePrams.connected)
            }]
        }
    }
```

As a result, I could call in a html:

```
   <a href="addin/edit/?connected=true" target="_self">New</a>
```

Now, I want to add another query parameter `ifi` in the url, I tried

```
    .state('addinEdit', {
        url: '/addin/edit/{id}?connected?ifi',
        resolve: {
            test: [$stateParams, function($stateParams) {
                console.log($statePrams.connected)
                console.log($statePrams.ifi)
            }]
        }
    }
```

But `<a href="addin/edit/?connected=true?ifi=true" target="_self">New</a>` does not seem to work.

When I see the url in a browser, it is `https://localhost:3000/1/#/addin/edit/?connected=true%3Fifi%3Dtrue`.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would use an `&` rather than another `?`:

```
'/addin/edit/{id}?connected&ifi',
```

Comment: @Marcel beat me to it, if you accept either of ours, it should be his.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `&` for additional params:

```
<a href="addin/edit/?connected=true&ifi=true" target="_self">New</a>
```

And the same in the route definition

```
 url: '/addin/edit/{id}?connected&ifi',
```